# Javascript function prevent to execute if already executing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function which job is to fetch the record from third party and this function is executing after each 10 seconds.

The problem is since this function is executing after very short time so when I debug through firefox it's showing a long queue of ajax. I am thinking why not to add a statement which can give the signal to next about ajax executions. Because I am executing same function and which job is same so if previous one still doing the same then there is not point to execute another one for the same job. I am trying following

```
function someThingPrecessing(){
    if(sessionStorage.do == true){
        $.ajax(function(){
            continue...
        });
     }

    sessionStorage.do = true;
    sessionStorage.do = false;
}

setInterval(someThingPrecessing,10000);
```

But above one does not working, can someone guide me how can I do that. I would like to appreciate.

Comment: What about just using a global flag to ensure the function is not executing already?

Comment: @briosheje yes true, but how ? can you give me some example ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the ajax request is done before calling the next one. Below is an example:

```
var ajax_ongoing=false;
function someThingPrecessing(){
    if(!ajax_ongoing){
    ajax_ongoing=true;
        $.ajax(function(){
            success : function(data) {
                    ajax_ongoing=false;
                },
                error : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    ajax_ongoing=false;
                }
        });
     }
  }

setInterval(someThingPrecessing,10000);
```

Comment: In this case, if success takes more time then? it will send ajax request

Comment: Why don't you try setTimeout?

Comment: if success takes time, the ajax_ongoing variable would stay true and the if(!ajax_ongoing) will be false, so it won't send another ajax request